# Ajax query 500 when adding variable of eloquent relation to Concatenation assignment in Laravel Controller, works fine without variable

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have an Ajax query that works correctly but when trying to add a variable to the concatenation assignment '$output' i get a 500 error.

This is for an application using laravel to display resources associated with selected topics. There are eloquent belongsToMany relationships from the topics to articles, lifts, quotes, and visuals that are inverse and are pulling properly

This is the ajax function in my controller:

```
public function action(Request $request)
{
 if($request->ajax())
 {
  $topics = Topics::orderBy('Topic', 'asc')->get();
  $output = '';
  $query = $request->get('query');
  //query
  if($query != '')
  {
   $data = DB::table('topics')
     ->where('topic', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
     ->where('slug', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
     ->get();
  }
  else
  {
    $data = $topics;
  }
  //updating variables with query data
  $total_row = $data->count();
  if($total_row > 0)
  {
   foreach($data as $row)
   {
    // combining resources associated with topics <-- $resource is the trouble variable!!
    $resource = $row->articles->count() + $row->lifts->count() + $row->visuals->count() + $row->quotes->count();
    $output .= '<tr><td><a href="/topics/'.$row->slug.'">'.$row->topic.'</a> '.$resource.'</td></tr>';
   }
  }
  else
  {
   $output = '<tr><td align="center" colspan="5">No Data Found</td></tr>';
  }
  $data = array(
   'table_data'  => $output
  );

  echo json_encode($data);
 }
}
```

my blade

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <title>Live search in laravel using AJAX</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
         <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Topics" />
         </div>
         <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
           <tbody>
           </tbody>
          </table>
         </div>
     </body>
    </html>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     fetch_topic_data();
     function fetch_topic_data(query = '')
     {
      $.ajax({
       url:"{{ route('live_search.action') }}",
       method:'GET',
       data:{query:query},
       dataType:'json',
       success:function(data)
       {
        $('tbody').html(data.table_data);
       }
      })
     }
     $(document).on('keyup', '#search', function(){
      var query = $(this).val();
      fetch_topic_data(query);
     });
    });
    </script>
```

Console errors

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/live_search/action?query=te 500 (Internal Server Error)
    send    @   jquery.min.js:4
    ajax    @   jquery.min.js:4
    fetch_topic_data    @   live_search:26
    (anonymous) @   live_search:39
    dispatch    @   jquery.min.js:3
    q.handle    @   jquery.min.js:3
```

With the $resource variable the query does not work but the topics are displayed properly on the page.

with $resource

[image: with $resource]

without $resource

[image: Without $resource]

When i remove $resource the query works but obviously I would like to display the topic and the query results with the amount of resources associated content to the topic like:

Socrates 1

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thank you for your time.

Comment: What is there in logs for that 500 error?

Comment: @KamalPaliwal updated the post with the console errors! It seems like it is a send error, but the query should only be pulling the topic and the slug from the db.

Comment: Any errors in the laravel logs?

Comment: @KamalPaliwal yes! `Undefined property: stdClass::$articles {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0)`

Comment: The last comma  in `$data = array('table_data'  => $output,  );`

Comment: @Roy thank you, I removed that and updated the post but it is still showing the `Undefined property` error

Comment: @TonyGarand As it is saying articles property is not defined on your $row. Try removing $row->articles->count() from the code once to be sure that this error belongs to there only.

Comment: @KamalPaliwal it is that whole $resource variable that is causing the error. since they are belongsToMany relation to topics, and they are objects.

Answer (score -1):

After some research and help I have found the solution!

Elsewhere someone suggested changing the DB query to a model query

```
    if($query != '')
    { 
    $data = DB::table('topics') ->where('topic', 'like', '%'.$query.'%') ->where('slug', 'like', '%'.$query.'%') ->get();
    } else { 
    $data = $topics; 
    }
```

Is now

```
    if($query != '')
    {
    $data = Topics::where('topic', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')->where('slug', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')->get();
    }
    else
    {
    $data = $topics;
    }
```

I was unaware you could this!

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#query-scopes